# Multiple relationships with single mapping table without generating foreign keys by Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, one-to-one, many-to-one

I have **two base abstract classes** and there are multiple additional classes derived from these two, adding additional attributes etc.

There exist relations between those specific derived types.

**A simple illustrating example:**

`Role` and `Group` classes are `abstract`, but they are not marked as `@MappedSuperclass`.

`InheritanceType.JOINED` strategy is being used, so both tables `Role` (for abstract class) and `AdminRole` (for derived class) should exist (they both will have the same `RoleID`).

- `DiscussionGroup` has one `AdminRole` property, a
  `Set<DiscussantRole>`, a `Set<ManagerRole>`
- `WorkingGroup` has `Set<WorkerRole>`, `Set<ManagerRole>`

> ```
> Role 
> |-- AdminRole
> |-- DiscussantRole
> |-- ManagerRole
> |-- WorkerRole
>
> Group
> |-- DiscussionGroup
> |-- WorkingGroup
> ```

Because the number of derived classes can grow, and because classes derived from Role can have relations to different classes derived from Group (and vice versa) this would lead to a large amount of different mapping tables (Worker_DiscussionGroup, Worker_WorkingGroup) or multiple foreign key columns (in M:1 relationships - e.g. a ManagerRole would have to have DiscussionGroupID and WorkingGroupId). **I want to map all these relations through one common mapping table.**

```
Role_Group (RoleID, GroupId)
```

We use **Hibernate to generate the DDL schema (hbm2ddl.auto=create)** during current development (we will use a static schema definition for later production use). Hibernate automatically creates Foreign keys for the relations, and thats quite good for us.

If I instruct it to use the same mapping  a table for joins (for the many-to-many, many-to-many and for one-to-one as well), **it will try to create foreign keys** as well. And it is of course not possible to create a foreign key on `RoleID` from `Role_Group` to `AdminRole` and `DiscussantRole` at the same time, so I get an error.

**Is there any way, how to instruct Hibernate**

1. **to generate selected relationships without foreign keys**

   or
2. **to define that the relation should be based on the abstract
   ancestors (i.e. DiscussionGroup and its Set should
   be mapped as 1:N - Group and Set)?**

Answer (score 4):

Following works for me as an answer for question number 2:

```
@ForeignKey( name = "none" )
```

No foreign key is being generated for the relationship.

```
@Cascade( value = { CascadeType.ALL } )
@OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true )
@JoinTable( name = "Role_Group",
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn( referencedColumnName = "rolleId", name = "RolleID" ) },
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( referencedColumnName = "groupId", name = "GroupID" ) } )

@ForeignKey( name = "none" )
public AdminRole getAdmin()
```

Sources:

- [Disabling foreign key generation in hbm2ddl](http://blog.cherouvim.com/disabling-foreign-key-generation-in-hbm2ddl/)
- [Forcing hbm2ddl to not generate an FK](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=978321)

Based on the sources, it is an undocumented feature which was seen in release notes:

```
Changes in version 2.1.9 (xx.x.xxxx)
------------------------------------
* TimesTenDialect now supported (look at TimesTenDialect for certain limitations)
* foreign-key="none" can be used to disable generation of a foreign key.
```

In xml config - you would use it like this

```
<many-to-one name="Hospital" column="hospitalId" property-ref="hospitalId" update="false" insert="false" foreign-key="none">
```

as mentioned in [Let Hibernate Connect Your World!](http://blog.xebia.com/2007/02/let-hibernate-connect-your-world/) (see the page sources - xml configuration is not shown on the page)

**Note:**

This does not solve the whole problem however. Hibernate cannot get the right data through this mapping table for `getAdmin` and `getManagers` as well, because it looks to `Role_Group`, finds `RoleIDs` for `DiscussionGroup` `GroupID` and has no idea if it is for `AdminRole` or `ManagerRole` and gives "*No row with the given identifier exists" error*".

Simimilar mapping works however when I use such table in Group or DiscussionGroup as `public Set<Role> getRoles()`, Hibernate will successfully load derived classes (`AdminRole`, `ManagerRole`) to the Set.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should keep multiple tables.  It just maps the relationship that exists in your classes.

If you don't want that then you could define a `Set<Role>` inside abstract `Group` and a `Set<Group>` in abstract `Role`.  You would not have any "subsets" in the subclasses; you just fill the set from the abstract class with the appropriate elements of the right type.  The automatic mapping would then give you a single join table like you want.