# JPA association without foreign key

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to set up a ManyToOne association without JPA creating a foreign key in the database?

The tables are owned by another system and are populated asynchronously. Thus we can't have a FK in the database. There's still, almost always, eventually a relation.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="`Order Type`", referencedColumnName = "`Order Type`", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name="`Order No`", referencedColumnName = "`No`", insertable = false, updatable = false)
}, foreignKey = @javax.persistence.ForeignKey(value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
private OrderHeader orderHeader;
```

The problem is that JPA SchemaUpdate tries to add a FK even though ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT

> > [error] o.h.t.h.SchemaUpdate - Cannot add foreign key constraint

and we could ignore that if it didn't make the rest of the statements fail

> > [error] o.h.t.h.SchemaUpdate - No operations allowed after statement closed.

We're on hibernate-entitymanager 4.3.7.Final and JPA 2.1.

Comment: Are you using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`? If yes, what if you set its value to `none`?

Comment: We want to auto generate for all other entities / tables. I thought this would disable auto generation for all.

Comment: Yes, it would disable it for all. I think it's not possible to configure it to ignore only specific classes/fields. If you do disable it, does everything else work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The fact that ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT is ignored looks like a bug in Hibernate 4 due to be fixed in 5.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8805

The comments on that and indeed this post here:

[Multiple relationships with single mapping table without generating foreign keys by Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313463/multiple-relationships-with-single-mapping-table-without-generating-foreign-keys)

suggest adding the deprecated (hibernate rather than JPA) annotation

```
@ForeignKey( name = "none" )
```

to the relationship should work.

Answer (score 8):

Add `name="none"` in `javax.persistence.ForeignKey`,

this worked for me.

```
foreignKey = @javax.persistence.ForeignKey(name="none",value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Hibernate 4.3.X annotation field with @org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey( name = "none") worked for me.

But be carefull: **in case of bidirectional relationships, you have to annotate two fields by mentionad annotation!!!**