# hbm2ddl - How to avoid that Hibernate is creating Foreign Key constraints?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, hbm2ddl

Dear all I am using Hibernate with hbm2ddl. I don't like that for one relationship foreign key constraints get created. Unfortunately I could not achieve it so far. I tried it with Hibernate and JPA annotations, had no luck.
Any hints?

I am using Hibernate 4.3.1 and mysql 5.6

```
@Entity
class Artikel {
   ...
   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="artikel")
   @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
   private List<Bild> images;
}

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.ForeignKey;
@Entity
class Bild {
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey(name = "none") 
  @JoinColumn(name="idKey",  insertable=false, updatable=false, 
    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="none",value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)) 
  private Artikel artikel;
}
```

It always creates the foreign key: FK_k93uxcqtc87jifh2j3rliumuj for table "bild" on column "idKey":
Error during import: "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`skateshop`.`bild`, CONSTRAINT `FK_k93uxcqtc87jifh2j3rliumuj` FOREIGN KEY (`idKey`) REFERENCES `artikel` (`id`))"

Comment: The fact that is creates an FK is a good thing. It allows detecting that the data you want to import is incoherent, and needs to be fixed for your app to work correctly: you have a build that belongs to an artikel that doesn't exist. Fix your data, and leave the constraint there. It makes sure your data stays in a coherent state.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and I would also agree to that. But unfortunately I am not the owner of the data and I have to consume it, I can delete the inconsistencies after I made the import. so I need to find a way to disable and enable foreignkeys during import

Answer (score 2):

You are using the correct annotation:

```
@ForeignKey(value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)
```

It looks like a bug in hibernate 4.x that is now fixed in 5.x. If you could upgrade to Hibernate 5.x, that would solve the issue.

See also [JPA association without foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040735/jpa-association-without-foreign-key)